# Excel date formatation

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm doing some work on an already done excel program, but I'm very rusty in this area or probably never had done something in this part, I'm very new in VBA so please don't judge me if it's a simple mistake or error the links are in the description.

So I have problem where if I put the confirmation option, for example: in one cell press "1" in the product you have, and in another cell write "S" if you already have the product and it puts you a date of today in another cell.

The problem is when I delete the info that I inserted, and reenter it the date deformats itself becoming smaller and the location on the cell changes too.

I'm going to put the links because, like I said I'm rusty and I can't find where the code of this date comes.

http://www.docdroid.net/12dh4/master-atual-20155.xls.html -->This one is the Excel

http://www.docdroid.net/12dhj/errorphotos.pdf.html --> photos showing error

this is the code of one of the sheets the other ones are almost the same, If you guys see the photos it would help to understand the error itself.

So the main issue is that, I wasn't being able to format the date option it always changes the font and the custom selected date. And I already changed the option of the cell, if you guys can help by showing or leading me there.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("v3:v500"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

 On Error Resume Next


    If rng1.Value <> "" Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()
    Else
        rng1.Offset(0, 2).Clear
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: With respect to the date format look at [this](http://bit.ly/1HfLuuJ).  What do you mean that the location on the cells change too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem, the issue is this line:

```
rng1.Offset(0, 2).Clear
```

That line clears everything, including the underlying format.  To have it so the format is retained, merely change to

```
rng1.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks sooo muchhh It was so basic, but without your help I would be stuck thanks very much

Comment: Glad to help.  Sometimes another pair of eyes is useful.  And fortunately, you presented all the necessary information in your first post (something that does not always happen).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

change the following line code

```
  rng1.Offset(0, 2).Clear
```

to

```
 rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
```

Comment: Thanks Both yours information and Ron's helped me alot, without you guys I wouldnt got there.